# Error in adding toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to add a toolbar to my app instead of Action bar. But when i add toolbar to my app, my app crashes and i don't know how.

This is my code.

**ToolbarActivity.java**

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsdfs);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_toolbar.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color2</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

**LogCat**

```
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tech.Toolbar/com.tech.toolbar.ToolbarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1734)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1569)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:158)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:370)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:701)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:373)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:167)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:487)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2535)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9129)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:248)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:176)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:174)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:90)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:77)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at com.tech.toolbar.ToolBarActivity.onCreate(ToolBarctivity.java:12)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1698)
08-12 14:31:05.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18413):    ... 18 more
08-12 14:31:05.920: E/dalvikvm(18413): [DVM] mmap return base = 45e92000
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
         >
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Tab"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity 
           android:name=".ToolBarActivity"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />            

            </application>
```

I have tried everything possible to achieve my goal but to no avail. My app min SDK is 10. I am using eclipse Luna for development.

Comment: why is toolbar inside a scrollview?. Also extend `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: How to extend AppCompatActivity and where to extend it?

Comment: Error is coming from the FeedbackActivity not from ToolbarActivity - `FeedbackActivity.onCreate(FeedbackActivity.java:12)`

Comment: Sorry but FeedbackActivity and ToolBarActivity is one and the same activity. Now i edited my question. Please answer now. @Ganesh

Comment: Sure that the error have to do with Toolbar? See logcat. There is one line with `com.ansari.islamicthings.ToolBarActivity` and another with `com.tech.toolbar.ToolbarActivity`which is now your activity and what is your package name?!
Have you tried to start this activity without the toolbar?
And what is line 12 in your activity?

Comment: updated my question. and yes without toolbar its working fine. Line 12 = setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar); @StefMa

Comment: Things I'd do (all together): (1) move the Toolbar outside the ScrollView, I'm pretty sure you can't do that (if you really need to call setActionBar, at least); (2) extend AppCompatActivity, not ActionBarActivity; (3) remove windowActionBar=false from your style; (4) change app:theme to android:theme in the Toolbar declaration. If it works then, you can try to see which of the four things was causing your issue.

Comment: I tried doing all the things but i am getting the same error @m vai

Comment: Are you sure you have a proper `Toolbar` import? and not something like `import com.tech.Toolbar;` instead of `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`?

Comment: Yeah I am sure i have a proper import, its import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; .

Comment: I guess there is no need to extend Activity with AppCompatActivity,
U have to add android-support-v7-appcompat lib in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find a view that is **`NULL`**.

Your code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Your xml:

```
android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
```

**ERROR!!**

If you are trying to find your `Toolbar`, you've to put the ID of your `Toolbar` correctly!!

Your code of `Toolbar` should be:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsdfs);
```

By the way, change your "class extends" to this:

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Hope it work :)

### Edit

Okay. I've created a sample, tell me if I misunderstood your words, and I'll tell you what I've done.

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#f0f0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#f3f</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsdfs);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes this is what i want bro.

Comment: Feel free to use my code, if you need more help message me ;) Happy coding ^^

Comment: Thanks brother its working. I will award my bounty to you in 22 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

this should be the declaration of your class, otherwise the theme with noActionBar and the class ActionBarActivity will create a conflict.

Comment: No, app is still crashing even after extending AppCompatActivity.

Comment: what does logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your toolbar inside of `ScrollView` and add it outside of your `ScrollView`.

**Try this snippet**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In addition your activity should extend `AppCompatActivity`. `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

EDIT 1:
Also you should add this line to your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Maybe this help.

Comment: Nope it is still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` which is for no action bar screen. Try to use something like `parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid"`

Comment: It's the other way around: ["In order to use a Toolbar within the Activity's window content the application must *not* request the window feature FEATURE_ACTION_BAR."](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar%28android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar%29) - .NoActionBar for ToolBar because stock (API 11) actionbar isn't as cool as custom compat one.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(Toolbar ID);
setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resourses.getString(R.string.register));
```

If it requires:

```
/*mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();

    }
});*/
```

Toolbar XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

**Note:** I guess there is no need to extend Activity with AppCompatActivity,
U have to add android-support-v7-appcompat lib in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use them Theme.AppCompat.Light in place of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color2</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code to a new project and it's working for me! My ToolbarActivity is (do you import `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`?):

```
package bendaf.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class ToolbarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarsdfs);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="bendaf.example" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ToolbarActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

my style**s**.xml (do you name it correctly?):

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and my activity_toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarsdfs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope you find the difference, my test phone runs android 5.0.1 and it's working on that.

Answer (score 0):

in your style.xml,try this:-

```
    <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

</style>
```

Hope it might help